# Update Gnome from the original in 14.4.2 to 3.16

Tags: 14.04

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 Kernel 3.16.0-43-generic gnome 3.9.90
```

on a HP AMD 5600.

I want to know if I can update to Gnome 3.16 without compatibility problems with the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* upgrade to GNOME 3.16. A GUI doesn't affects your kernel.

But it's not simple, because there are no PPAs with GNOME 3.16 for Trusty.